# Using Cauchy Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, entire-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

If i had some function $g(f(z)) $ and wanted to use the Cauchy Riemann equations to check if it's entire how would I get $ g(f(z))$ in the form $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ if the functions were real we would usually use the chain rule?
For example how would I use the Cauchy Riemann equations to check of something like $sin(sin(z))$

Comment: You can use the Chain Rule with complex variables too

Comment: I understand but how would I get it into the form above, as I want to use  the Cauchy Riemann equations

Comment: If $f(z) = a+ib$, then we have $u$ is a function of $a$ and $b$. Hence by Chain Rule: $u_x = u_a \cdot a_x + u_b \cdot b_x$ and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h=g(f(z))=h_r+ih_i$ and let $w=f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.  Then, we have from the chain rule

$$\frac{h_r}{\partial x}=g_r'u_x-g_i'v_x$$

and

$$\frac{\partial h_i }{\partial y}=g_i'u_y+g_r'v_y $$

If $f$ is analytic, then $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$.  Hence, if $g$ is differentiable and $f$ is analytic, then $\frac{\partial h_r}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial y}$.

Can you show that the other CRE is satisfied?

Comment: Brilliant, & I will try to show the other crew is satisfied now, would you be able to show me an example of using the Cauchy Riemann equations to show the function $sin(z^{2})$ is entire ?